# LibreOffice: indent all lines starting with italic via find/replace

Tags: libreoffice, find, regex

I have a huge text, and I would like to indent all lines which start with italic text, via find/replace.

I tried using ^ and italic via the format button, but then the search string is not found.

If I fill in ^. and italic (via the format button), then due to the dot it finds the search strings, but then my first letter is disappearing everywhere when I enter \t in the replace box.

So how to deal with this?

Comment: Check https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer

Answer (score 0):

Find: `^(.earch)`
Replace: `\t$1`

`$1` is the placeholder for the first item in the search string that is within braces. `\t` represents the tab character.

Comment: It looks like you intended to write `^(.)` as the Find pattern. Then it works.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I missed the $1 part